# How to calculate max-height of grid-template-row: auto?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to implement a scrollbar inside a child element, rather than a scrollbar for the whole page. In order to do so, I should set a `max-height` for the `main` tag.

In order to sit nicely within the *grid*, i believe i have to calculate the `max-height` of `grid-template-row: auto`.

I think i could use something like `max-height: minmax (FOO, BAR)`

But, I don't know how to identify *FOO* or *BAR*.

I'd appreciate any help you can offer!

```css
/* removes codepen's scrollbar */
* {overflow: hidden}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto min-content;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* This is the problem */
  max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  /* 
  I believe that max-height is calculated as max-height: minmax (FOO, BAR);
  But, i dont know how to identify / calculate FOO or BAR!
  */
}

header {
  background-color: coral;
  padding: inherit;
}

main {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: inherit;
}

footer {
  background: skyblue;
  padding: inherit;
}

p, h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h2>header</h2>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h2>main</h2>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <h2>footer</h2>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the `max-height` *property*, use the `height` instead:

```css
body {margin: 0}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto min-content; /* can also use "1fr" instead of "auto" */
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh; /* modified */
}

main {
  overflow-y: auto; /* recommended; i.e. don't show it if not needed */
}

header {
  background-color: coral;
  padding: inherit;
}

main {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: inherit;
}

footer {
  background: skyblue;
  padding: inherit;
}

p, h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h2>header</h2>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h2>main</h2>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
    <p>THIS IS FILLER!</p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <h2>footer</h2>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect.  A much better, and more straight-forward solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do auto-fit or auto-fill, here example:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
```

Comment: I have used columns in my project.  However, i removed the unnecessary code for this question.  I need to calculate the max-height, so as to seemlessly position the rows. In the example, i just used and arbitrary number. Thanks for this advice, but i dont think it addresses the height issue.